# What size of screw do I need to fix a 26" TV to a brick wall?

Tags: walls, mounting

What size of screw do I need to fix a 26" TV to a brick wall? The mounting kit included four 65mm screws which does seem excessive since the TV weighs 9kg.

Can I use a smaller size?

Comment: 9 kilograms isn't a huge amount by itself, but when you're talking of something that can indiscriminately drop onto passing children, you do want to anchor it correctly. remember, vibrations when walking necessitate strong supports.

Comment: 65mm long are not 'too long' I think. Besides that over-security matters that alt (up) indicated, I would add, that the farther TV is from the wall, the bigger support it needs to have (cantilever!). On top of that I say that IF mounting kit's producer supplied it with these 65mm long screws, I would reccomend using LONGER screws, not smaller ones! (in case of some accident You may complain about supplied screws)

Comment: Why is it you would *want* to use a smaller size?

Answer (score 1):

Use the longest screw you can without excessively damaging the wall. It's far better to have a more stable installation than chancing the television from falling.

Looking at it another way, if you use screws that are too small and are forced to redo the job, you're going to have more damage from the original installation than you would have if you had just used larger screws to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

The mounting kit likely came with wood screws. You need masonry schools for this job. Tapcon are common ones:

[image]

You need to pre-drill all the holes into the brick/mortar the use these types of screws to anchor things.